# How to correctly databind collection to TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

I've looked at several qustions/answers on SO and for some reason I'm not getting anything to work for binding a collection to the `TabControl`. I am trying to do this so I don't *have* to assign the `DataContext` in the code-behind.

Here is the view model:

```
public class DocumentsCollectionViewModel : IEnumerable<DocumentViewModel> {

    private readonly ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel> mDocsCollection = new ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel> Documents {
        get { return mDocsCollection; }
    }

    // initially excluded from question as I thought it was understood :)
    public IEnumerator<DocumentViewModel> GetEnumerator() {
        return mDocsCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return mDocsCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

...for completeness sake, the `DocumentViewModel`:

```
public class DocumentViewModel {

    private readonly Document mDocument;


    public string Name {
        get { return mDocument.Name; }
    }

}
```

In the XAML, I am a little confused about where to tell the tab control to use the `Documents` property in `DocumentsCollectionViewModel`:

```
<TabControl Name="DocumentsTab"
            ItemsSource="{Binding localmodels:DocumentsCollectionViewModel}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localmodels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                   Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localmodels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                   Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the `DataContext` of your `Window`/UserControl which has this `TabControl` to the instance of your `DocumentsCollectionViewModel`?

Try doing this in the constructor of your Window containing the TabControl

```
public void MainWindow()
{

     InitializeComponents();
     this.DataContext = new DocumentsCollectionViewModel();
     //Initialize the collection inside your VM
}
```

OR you can set DataContext in xaml like

```
<Window>
   <Window.DataContext>
       <localmodels:DocumentsCollectionViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

then in your xaml just directly bind to `Documents` property

```
<TabControl Name="DocumentsTab"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localmodels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                   Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localmodels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                   Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: This works but I was severely reprimanded for manually setting the `DataContext`.

Comment: @IAbstract you can set DataContext in xaml like shown in updated answer

Comment: Ah, very well. When you do this, an instance of `DocumentsCollectionViewModel` is created but where does the instance *live*? Say, when I want to add documents to the collection?